# How to create an 'onClick' event for form submit button which both POSTS data to Netlify and redirects to Stripe Checkout?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, netlify, stripe-payments, netlify-form

My site code is housed @ https://github.com/CB-Essential-Services/adorable-chestnut/blob/staging-3/src/components/checkout.js

I am running a Netlify -- Gatsby -- StripeCheckout stack.

**Issue:** I need the `submit` button in the code below to both submit form data to Netlify Forms and using an '*onClick*' event `redirectToCheckout` to process payment with Stripe.

```
Checkout.js
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

import _ from 'lodash';

function encode(data) {
    return Object.keys(data)
      .map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
      .join('&')
  }

let stripePromise
const getStripe = () => {
  if (!stripePromise) {
    stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_RlvibjeKdvwY81acv2YLwvTM00I3UsWXIi")
  }
  return stripePromise
}

const Checkout = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const redirectToCheckout = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

    const stripe = await getStripe()
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      mode: "subscription",
      lineItems: [{ price: "price_1Gva5YAeKYVunD5viRkFzoR7", quantity: 1 }],
      successUrl: `http://localhost:8000/thanks/`,
      cancelUrl: `http://localhost:8000/404`,
    })

    if (error) {
      console.warn("Error:", error)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  return (    
<form
    name="transfer"
    method="POST"
    content-type= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
    data-netlify="true"
    id="transfer"
    className="transfer"
>
    <p className="screen-reader-text">
        <label>Don't fill this out if you're human: <input name="bot-field" /></label>
    </p>
    <p className="form-row">
        <label htmlFor="transfer-name" className="form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="transfer-name" className="form-input" />
    </p>
    <p className="form-row">
        <label htmlFor="transfer-email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="transfer-email" className="form-input" />
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="transfer" value="transfer" />
    <p className="form-row form-submit">
        <button type="submit" className="button" 
        disabled={loading}
      onClick={redirectToCheckout}>
          Pay
          </button>
    </p>
</form>
  )
}

export default Checkout
```

The `redirectToCheckout` part works fine. Stripe dev support said I should be able to submit form data to Netlify --> [initial convo w/Stripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9gyD.jpg)  [secondary convo w/Stripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNaGB.jpg)

In summary, Stripe dev support said **Yes, I could use `redirectToCheckout` at any point on the frontend**. For instance, submit form data to Netlify using AJAX, then while resolving the result `redirectToCheckout`.

That's a different method than what I'm doing. I have no idea how utilize AJAX!

But they also implied the process is fluid. My way should be fine. I just need to figure out how to POST the data to Netlify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand and redirect your flow-through `redirectToCheckout` function once all the validations have been done.

Assuming that your `redirectToCheckout` function is pushing properly your data to Stripe, you only need to pass your data to Netlify and make a simple redirection.

```
  const redirectToCheckout = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

   // form validations here. If passed the validation, send data to Stripe and Netlify

    const stripe = await getStripe()
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      mode: "subscription",
      lineItems: [{ price: "price_1Gva5YAeKYVunD5viRkFzoR7", quantity: 1 }],
      successUrl: `http://localhost:8000/thanks/`,
      cancelUrl: `http://localhost:8000/404`,
    })


    fetch(`/`, {
      method: `POST`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
      },
      body: encode({
        'form-name': `transfer`,
        ...data, // here you need to pass your data object
      }),
    })
      .then(() => console.log(`OK`)) // navigate to desired page
      .catch(error => alert(error));
    };

    if (error) {
      console.warn("Error:", error)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

There are a lot of things in the snippet above. First of all, make sure to validate your data properly and creating a data object with `key`-`value` pairs for all your fields before sending it to your Stripe API or Netlify, you should need to validate your form before.

Then, you only need to create an asynchronous request using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (JavaScript built-in) or using [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) for example. When dealing with Netlify forms, the data structure is very important and it's mandatory to have exactly the needed information to pass. You can check [this article for further details](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/).

Once your promise ended successfully, you only need to change the `` console.log(`OK`) `` for a `navigate("/your-page")`.

Comment: Thanks Ferran. I added the data object successfully and it passes the values over for a successful submission -- without redirectToCheckout. Adding it as 'onClick" event seems to override completing the Netlify process.

Is it 100% necessary for me to use 'fetch'? My success page is defined in redirectToCheckout.

Comment: In other words: Can I redirectToCheckout from '.then(() =>'?

Comment: fetch is used to make an AJAX request to Netlify, the other values are not mandatory. And of course, you can use the then() to call another function. Maybe adding your `stripe.redirectToCheckout` inside the `then()` works for you.